# How to hide columns based on column label using scripts?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have days of the month as columns on a Google Spreadsheet. I am trying to write a script to Autohide the columns based on which month is selected from the drop down list in Cell A2.

So far I have been able to find a script where I can autohide column if value in Row1 is 0. But I have been having issues in implementing the same. I have used a IF(OR) formula to display 0 in columns that are to be hidden [enclosed screenshot below].

[image]

This is the script I have come up with so far, but it isn't working.

```
 oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
oSheet1 = oSheets.getByName("MIS")
oColumns = oSheet1.getColumns()
var i=1;
while (i < 34) // continue running the loop while i is less than 34
{
   oCol = oColumns.getByIndex(i)
   oCell = oSheet1.getCellByPosition(i,0);
  if (oCell.Value = 0) { oCol.isVisible = False;}
  else {oCol.isVisible = True}
i++; }
```

Is there a mistake in the code? I am relatively new to spreadsheet and completely new to Scripts and have no coding background, hence the confusion.

Comment: Hi, the code you posted uses a programming interface named UNO (Universal Network Objected) provided by Apache OpenOffice. Therefore you can’t use it in Google Apps. Google Apps script is a scripting language based on JavaScript. Please take a look at the [overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know either of the programming languages, thats the reason I wasnt able to understand why it was not working. I found syntax for JavaScript and managed to get it done referring to a blog post. Ill update the code that I used so that it may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from k4k4sh1 I was able to get the right code for this particular script to work.

You also have to set up a project trigger after saving this function.

I referred to this blog post: [Customise Google Docs-Blogspot](http://customizegoogledocs.blogspot.in/2015/05/hiding-certain-cells-in-google.html)

```
function HideColumns() {
  //open the current spreadsheet and get the value of the named range
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var name = ss.getRangeByName("monthfilter");
   var namevalue = name.getValue();

  //show or hide February
  if (namevalue == "February") {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MIS");
    sheet.hideColumns(30);
    sheet.hideColumns(31);
    sheet.hideColumns(32);
  }

  //show or hide 30 day months
    else if (namevalue == "April"||namevalue == "June"||namevalue == "September"||namevalue == "November") {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MIS");
    sheet.showColumns(30);
    sheet.showColumns(31);
    sheet.hideColumns(32);
  }

   //show or hide 31 day months
    else if (namevalue == "January"||namevalue == "March"||namevalue == "July"||namevalue == "August"||namevalue == "October"||namevalue == "December") {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MIS");
    sheet.showColumns(30);
    sheet.showColumns(31);
    sheet.showColumns(32);
    }
}
```